# python issue: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, class, typeerror

There is a problem when I execute the python code below, as follows

```
try:
    ipkt_payload = struct.pack("I", 0) * 10
    ipkt = testutils.simple_udp_packet(eth_dst='11:11:11:11:11:11',
                                       eth_src='22:22:22:22:22:22',
                                       ip_src='1.2.3.4',
                                       ip_dst='100.99.98.97',
                                       ip_id=101,
                                       ip_ttl=64,
                                       udp_sport=0x1234,
                                       udp_dport=0xabcd,
                                       with_udp_chksum=False,
                                       udp_payload=ipkt_payload)

    testutils.send_packet(self, swports[0], ipkt)

    (rcv_dev, rcv_port, rcv_pkt, pkt_time) = \
        testutils.dp_poll(self, 0, swports[1], timeout=2)
    nrcv = ipkt.__class__(rcv_pkt)
```

This is open source, and full code source 
Here's [a link](https://github.com/barefootnetworks/Open-Tofino/blob/master/p4-examples/p4_16_programs/tna_timestamp/test.py)!

The issue may come from "nrcv = ipkt.**class**(rcv_pkt)" 
error log:

```
ERROR: test.TimestampTest

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bf-sde-9.5.0/pkgsrc/p4-examples/p4_16_programs/tna_timestamp/test.py", line 73, in runTest
    nrcv = ipkt.__class__(rcv_pkt)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.203s

FAILED (errors=1)
()
******************************************
ATTENTION: SOME TESTS DID NOT PASS!!!
()
The following tests errored:
TimestampTest
()
******************************************
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Where are you importing from? I'd assume this code is within a class, since you're using self, what class are you writing? What is testutils?

Comment: I am attaching the full code link.

Comment: Thanks Chocolate. Can you post the entire stack trace? At which line does it fail? Thanks!

Comment: I am attaching the full error log.

Comment: From the error message, it appears `rcv_pkt` has two parameters, instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you very clearly what the problem is.

When you call a member function of an object, the first parameter is filled in for you automatically as the object itself.  Any additional parameters you pass are added to it, so if you call the function with one parameter it will actually get two.

A class is an object too.